# Bomb lab phase 5 - indexing an array with the low bits of input characters, summing the result?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, reverse-engineering

I know the problem is to input 6 values and make the sum to 67 by running the loop, but I don't know what the 6 values are. I would like to know the answer and the process.
I tried typing bdfrmo, fhjrmo, afrmno, dfgrmo... etc and it failed. I want to know what's wrong.

```
**
   0x0000555555555812 <+0>: endbr64 
   0x0000555555555816 <+4>: push   %rbx
   0x0000555555555817 <+5>: mov    %rdi,%rbx
   0x000055555555581a <+8>: callq  0x555555555aec <string_length>
   0x000055555555581f <+13>:    cmp    $0x6,%eax
   0x0000555555555822 <+16>:    jne    0x555555555850 <phase_5+62>
   0x0000555555555824 <+18>:    mov    %rbx,%rax
   0x0000555555555827 <+21>:    lea    0x6(%rbx),%rdi
   0x000055555555582b <+25>:    mov    $0x0,%ecx
   0x0000555555555830 <+30>:    lea    0x19a9(%rip),%rsi        # 0x5555555571e0 <array.3473>
   0x0000555555555837 <+37>:    movzbl (%rax),%edx
   0x000055555555583a <+40>:    and    $0xf,%edx
   0x000055555555583d <+43>:    add    (%rsi,%rdx,4),%ecx
   0x0000555555555840 <+46>:    add    $0x1,%rax
   0x0000555555555844 <+50>:    cmp    %rdi,%rax
   0x0000555555555847 <+53>:    jne    0x555555555837 <phase_5+37>
   0x0000555555555849 <+55>:    cmp    $0x43,%ecx
   0x000055555555584c <+58>:    jne    0x555555555857 <phase_5+69>
   0x000055555555584e <+60>:    pop    %rbx
   0x000055555555584f <+61>:    retq   
   0x0000555555555850 <+62>:    callq  0x555555555dfd <explode_bomb>
   0x0000555555555855 <+67>:    jmp    0x555555555824 <phase_5+18>
   0x0000555555555857 <+69>:    callq  0x555555555dfd <explode_bomb>
   0x000055555555585c <+74>:    jmp    0x55555555584e <phase_5+60>
**
```

and # 0x5555555571e0 <array.3473> is

```
2  10  6   1 
12 16  9   3
4  7   14  5
11 8   15  13
```

Comment: What logic did you use to come up with the inputs? Show your work.

Comment: Have you tried single-stepping this function while it processes your input?  You should see the sum accumulating in ECX, and so on.

Comment: @Jester I just picked 6 of the numbers in the array and added it to become 67, but when it was about 30 times I couldn't, so I quit. sorry I have poor skill

Comment: You have the code, you can run it. Anyway, what numbers did you pick? How did you map those to letters? [Edit] your question.

Comment: @PeterCordes I get a message that I can't access ecx because I don't have the bomb on my server.

Comment: Sorry, last two of 13 is changed 15 13.

Comment: Show which numbers you picked and how you mapped those to the letters.

Comment: @Jester 2 is a, 10 is b, 6 is c.....15 is o, 13 is p

Comment: `2` is not `a`. Hint: consult an ascii table. Hint #2: array indexing starts from zero.

Comment: That disassembly looks like it's from GDB; that means you're running GDB on the binary, so you should be able to actually run the program inside GDB.  Use `run` to start it running instead of just disassembling.  (If you just want disassembly, might as well just use `objdump -drwC -Mintel` instead of using GDB only for disassembly)

Comment: thanks guys, 10 is a.....truly happy, answer is dlllll.